# Swift Button is not clickable on whole area

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a problem with a `UIButton`.  This is how I create it:

```
let backButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "backButton"), for: .normal)
    v.backgroundColor = .cyan
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

Constraints:

```
backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

I create the button with the extra area on purpose for a better UX.

**Problem:**
The button is only `clickable` at the left half of the button. Why is this happening? It should also be clickable on the *invisible* area (`.cyan` for a better understanding).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you share the code where you add the button in its superview ?

Comment: @Sonastra I did in the question, look at the `constraints`